# Largest value's address in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have 1 column with 200 numbers.
The number starts from zero, goes to a highest point(X), then reduces to minus value to the lowest(Y) and then increases. Finally it ends in zero. 
0 1 2.... 10 3 2 -1 ....-10 -9 -8... 0

I got the maximum value using

```
Sub Largest()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim X As Double
        Set rng = Sheet2.Range("B2:B201")
        X = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rng)
        Worksheets(1).Range("D3").Value = X
End Sub
```

and same for smallest value with Min(rng) as Y

I am trying to get the address of the found value X and Y as a string.

For example

Xadd is a string decleration ; Yadd is a string decleration

Xadd = address of X value ; Yadd = address of Y value

so that i can do further processing like directly using

range(Xadd:Yadd)

Most of the places I can find only tutorials to find the address by using msgbox but not as a string. You can see the attached picture.
If i plot a graph, it will be like this.

[image]

So If i get the range address of X and Y, I can split the loop into two curves

- Y to X
- X to Y

This is why i need to get address of X and Y as a string so i can feed them into loops and for further processing.

How to get the address as a string or is there any other way to tackle the problem?

Comment: So you have a value and you want to know the cell reference where that value resides, correct?

Comment: Yes. I need the value as a string...

Comment: ...not as a range?  It's doable either way but what are you going to use the string for, that wouldn't be better as a range?

Comment: Can there only be 1 max or min value in the range tested? Then sounds like use Find and use either the range returned or its Address as a a string accessed by .Address

Comment: @ashleedawg is I think what you are saying is right. I dont know about vba. I am new to this. So I am just asking how it can be. I am asking if i can get the address and store it in some string/variable or anything so i can use it again..

Comment: A cell *address* could be stored in a String variable.  Much more functionality can come from instead storing a (sort of) "pointer" to the location in a ***Range Object***.  Read [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Excel-VBA/articles/range-object-excel) ... or better yet, you need to hit Google to find a beginner's VBA tutorial to explain the difference between variables, objects, properties, methods, etc.  Depending on experience with other languages, it can be a bit confusing at first, but an important lesson.  It's far too much to explain here.

Comment: **This might be a good place to start: *[Excel VBA For Complete Beginners](http://www.homeandlearn.org/)***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function returns the address of the cell that contains the maximum value in the specified range (or an empty string if there's a problem, like if the range doesn't contain values):

```
Function maxMatch(rge As Range) As String

    Dim fnd As Range, mx As Double

    'get maximum value in range
    mx = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(rge)

    'get range object containing location of [mx]
    Set fnd = rge.Find(mx, , xlValues)

    'return address of first matched cell
    If Not fnd Is Nothing Then maxMatch = fnd.Address

End Function
```

It can be used in VBA or as a worksheet function.  Note that if there is more than one of value equal to the maximum, the function will find only the first one occurrence.

---

## Example usage:

### *Worksheet function:*

```
=MAXMATCH(A1:B50)
```

### *VBA function:*

```
Dim mySearchRange as Range
Set mySearchRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B50")
MsgBox MaxMatch(mySearchRange)
```

*...or simplified:*

```
MsgBox MaxMatch(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B50"))
```

---

If there's a need to find ***subsequent matches***, the formula could be adapted to loop as required.  It would use the [`Range.Find` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel) for the initial search and then loop through successive matches with the [`Range.FindNext` Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel).  (Not to be confused with the [`Range.Next` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-next-property-excel), which emulates the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, returning a reference to the "next cell".)

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Range.Find Method (Excel VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)
- MSDN : [Range.FindNext Method (Excel VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-findnext-method-excel)
- MSDN : [WorksheetFunction.Max Method (Excel VBA)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-max-method-excel)
- MSDN : [Object model (Excel VBA reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/object-model-excel-vba-reference)

Answer (score 1):

If you feel you are a beginner at *VBA*, you can shorten your code considerably.  In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(B2=MAX(B$2:B$201),CELL("address",B2),"")
```

and copy down.  in **D2** enter:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,C2:C201),"$","")
```

Then the *VBA* might be:

```
Sub qwerty()
    MsgBox "Maximums located at: " & Range("D2").Value
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

The approach above assumes that your version of Excel supports `TEXTJOIN()`.

If it does not, then omit the **D2** equation and use this macro instead:

```
Sub qwerty2()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        arr = .Transpose(Range("C2:C200"))
        v = Replace(.Trim(Replace(Join(arr, " "), "$", "")), " ", ",")
        MsgBox v
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: `TEXTJOIN` function is available in Excel 2016. User will get `#NAME?` error in other versions.